# Android: how to simulate back button to hide a keyboard?

Tags: android

This problem may seem trivial but I wasn't able to find any nice and simple solution.

I've got an activity with a EditText and a software 'back' Button which simply calls finish() method of activity.
When I click on the EditText, there is a soft keyboard shown to input the text.

I want to achieve the following functionality when clicking the 'back' button (exactly the same as it is with the hardware back button):

- when the Keyboard is hidden, the onClick method should call finish() to end the activity

- when the Keyboard is shown, the onClick methond should hide the keyboard.

Is there any simple way to do that?

Comment: you could check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/android-is-software-keyboard-shown

Comment: Why would you want to do exactly what the hardware back button does? There's a reason its there, and users will most probably find it more intuitive also.

Comment: the app will run on low cost tablets. Some of them do not have a back key easily accessed (they look like iPad so they have only one button in front).

Answer (score -1):

**Keyboard Pasition**
finding if keyboard is hidden or not?
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);

**Selection of Back Button**
1)First you have to detect the back key in functionality :
 here is code:
start changing the ‘Back’ button, behavior, you need to override the onKeyDown() 
method and than check if the desired button has been pressed:

```
  //Override the onKeyDown method  
    @Override  
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  
    {  
        //replaces the default 'Back' button action  
        if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)  
        {  
            //do whatever you want the 'Back' button to do  
            //as an example the 'Back' button is set to start a new Activity named 'NewActivity'  
            this.startActivity(new Intent(YourActivity.this,NewActivity.class));  
        }  
        return true;  
    }
```

at least for Android 2.0.

```
@Override  
public void onBackPressed()  
{  
    //do whatever you want the 'Back' button to do  
    //as an example the 'Back' button is set to start a new Activity named 'NewActivity'  
    this.startActivity(new Intent(YourActivity.this,NewActivity.class));  

    return;  
}
```